# Why doesn't boolean value switch?

Tags: java, swing, boolean

First I want to say thanks for any assistance. I'm relatively new to Java programming. I built a simple TicTacToe game, and I'm having a little trouble.

Every once in a while "X" or "O" will be played twice in a row. I have a boolean variable that is supposed to switch from true to false to change "X" to "O" as each player takes a turn, but for some reason it isn't switching at random times.

I'm thinking it may be a problem with Eclipse or something, because I don't understand why else it would do this.

Below is the code for the game:

```
public class gameMain {

    Boolean player = true;
    JPanel gameBoard;
    JButton[] b = new JButton[10];
    Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 99);
    ListenForButtons lfb = new ListenForButtons();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new gameMain();
            }
        });
    }

    public gameMain() {
        JFrame j = new JFrame("TicTacToe");
        j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        j.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        j.setSize(400, 400);

        gameBoard = new JPanel();
        gameBoard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));

        b[1] = new JButton("");
        b[1].addActionListener(lfb);
        b[1].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b[1].setFont(font);
        b[1].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 2, Color.BLACK));
        b[2] = new JButton("");
        b[2].addActionListener(lfb);
        b[2].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b[2].setFont(font);
        b[2].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 2, 0, Color.BLACK));
        b[3] = new JButton("");
        b[3].addActionListener(lfb);
        b[3].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b[3].setFont(font);
        b[3].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 2, 2, 0, Color.BLACK));
        b[4] = new JButton("");
        b[4].addActionListener(lfb);
        b[4].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b[4].setFont(font);
        b[4].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 2, Color.BLACK));
        b[5] = new JButton("");
        b[5].addActionListener(lfb);
        b[5].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b[5].setFont(font);
        b[5].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));
        b[6] = new JButton("");
        b[6].addActionListener(lfb);
        b[6].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b[6].setFont(font);
        b[6].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 2, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));
        b[7] = new JButton("");
        b[7].addActionListener(lfb);
        b[7].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b[7].setFont(font);
        b[7].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 0, 0, 2, Color.BLACK));
        b[8] = new JButton("");
        b[8].addActionListener(lfb);
        b[8].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b[8].setFont(font);
        b[8].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));
        b[9] = new JButton("");
        b[9].addActionListener(lfb);
        b[9].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        b[9].setFont(font);
        b[9].setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 2, 0, 0, Color.BLACK));

        gameBoard.add(b[1]);
        gameBoard.add(b[2]);
        gameBoard.add(b[3]);
        gameBoard.add(b[4]);
        gameBoard.add(b[5]);
        gameBoard.add(b[6]);
        gameBoard.add(b[7]);
        gameBoard.add(b[8]);
        gameBoard.add(b[9]);

        j.add(gameBoard);
        j.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ListenForButtons implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == b[1]) {
                setSquare(b[1]);
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b[2]) {
                setSquare(b[2]);
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b[3]) {
                setSquare(b[3]);
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b[4]) {
                setSquare(b[4]);
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b[5]) {
                setSquare(b[5]);
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b[6]) {
                setSquare(b[6]);
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b[7]) {
                setSquare(b[7]);
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b[8]) {
                setSquare(b[8]);
            }
            if (e.getSource() == b[9]) {
                setSquare(b[9]);
            }
            checkForWin();
        }
    }

    public void setSquare(JButton button) {
        if (player) {
            button.setText("X");
            player = false;
            button.removeActionListener(lfb);
        } else {
            button.setText("O");
            player = true;
            button.removeActionListener(lfb);
        }
    }

    public void checkForWin() {
        if ((b[1].getText().equals("X") && b[2].getText().equals("X") && b[3].getText().equals("X"))
                || (b[4].getText().equals("X") && b[5].getText().equals("X") && b[6].getText().equals("X"))
                || (b[7].getText().equals("X") && b[8].getText().equals("X") && b[9].getText().equals("X"))
                || (b[1].getText().equals("X") && b[4].getText().equals("X") && b[7].getText().equals("X"))
                || (b[2].getText().equals("X") && b[5].getText().equals("X") && b[8].getText().equals("X"))
                || (b[3].getText().equals("X") && b[6].getText().equals("X") && b[9].getText().equals("X"))
                || (b[1].getText().equals("X") && b[5].getText().equals("X") && b[9].getText().equals("X"))
                || (b[3].getText().equals("X") && b[5].getText().equals("X") && b[7].getText().equals("X"))) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "X WINS THE GAME!", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            resetBoard();
        } else if ((b[1].getText().equals("O") && b[2].getText().equals("O") && b[3].getText().equals("O"))
                || (b[4].getText().equals("O") && b[5].getText().equals("O") && b[6].getText().equals("O"))
                || (b[7].getText().equals("O") && b[8].getText().equals("O") && b[9].getText().equals("O"))
                || (b[1].getText().equals("O") && b[4].getText().equals("O") && b[7].getText().equals("O"))
                || (b[2].getText().equals("O") && b[5].getText().equals("O") && b[8].getText().equals("O"))
                || (b[3].getText().equals("O") && b[6].getText().equals("O") && b[9].getText().equals("O"))
                || (b[1].getText().equals("O") && b[5].getText().equals("O") && b[9].getText().equals("O"))
                || (b[3].getText().equals("O") && b[5].getText().equals("O") && b[7].getText().equals("O"))) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "O WINS THE GAME!", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            resetBoard();
        } else if (!b[1].getText().equals("") && !b[2].getText().equals("") && !b[3].getText().equals("")
                && !b[4].getText().equals("") && !b[5].getText().equals("") && !b[6].getText().equals("")
                && !b[7].getText().equals("") && !b[8].getText().equals("") && !b[9].getText().equals("")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cats Game!", "", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            resetBoard();
        }
    }

    public void resetBoard() {
        for (int i = 1; i <= b.length - 1; i++) {
            b[i].setText("");
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= b.length - 1; i++) {
            b[i].addActionListener(lfb);
        }
        player = true;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Also, sometimes when resetBoard is called, one of the board squares doesn't reset.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and reduce it to the **relevant** code with which you're having problems. Expecting us to wade through all of your code to try and guess what part you're asking about is a little unreasonable. Also, please don't ask separate questions in the comments. If you have information to add to your question, edit your question and add it there. Thanks. :-)

Comment: give a "System.out.println(player + "");" to your setSquare, maybe the button hits twice, so check this - or it really is assign to your multiple randomly added actionlisteners like bmorris591 mentioned on the bottom...

Comment: `Also, sometimes when resetBoard is called, one of the board squares doesn't reset` The array index is zero-based in Java

Comment: Ignore the index base of the Array; that's what an enhanced for loop is for.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; @Ken White. This is my first post, I thought I would post everything so people could see what I had. I will try to make it more specific next time.

Comment: Please [edit] your question as I asked and fix **this one**, not just your next one. You're probably not getting much help because there's too much clutter. As it is now, it could be closed as "too localized", because you've included too much extra stuff to make it of general value to future readers here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `ResetBoard()` is called and not every button was pressed, then you end up having multiple `ActionListeners` assigned to those not used buttons.

Here is a example `resetBoard()` method:

```
    public void resetBoard() {
        // Fixed the loop index. Was: (int i = 1; i <= b.length - 1; i++)
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            b[i].setText("");
            // Adding a listener only if there isn't one already
            if (b[i].getActionListeners().length < 1) 
                b[i].addActionListener(lfb);
        }
        player = true;
    }
```

As @MadProgrammer suggested i refactored also the `setSquare()` method:

```
    public void setSquare(JButton button) {
        if (player) {
            button.setText("X");
        } else {
            button.setText("O");
        }
        button.removeActionListener(lfb);
        player = !player;
    }
```

Comment: Or just don't randomly re-add `ActionListeners`?

Comment: I'd also add that in the `setSquare` method, the need to explicitly set the `player` to `true` or `false` is unnecessary, simply using `player = !player` at the end of the method will 1- reduce code clutter and 2- achieve an absolute result, but your answer will better fix the problem

Comment: Thank you Martini, I didn't know there could be multiple listeners, this fixed my problem and makes perfect sense. Also MadProgrammer suggestion helped as well. Really appreciate the help!